How can I boot from a Thunderbolt disk with a kernel > 6.8.0-36?
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Since the kernel 6.8.0-36 has been updated to a newer version, I can no longer boot from my Thunderbolt disk.
Even with the current kernel 6.8.0-41 it does not work.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
If I boot with the old kernel 6.8.0-36 it still works, but I don't want to work with it forever.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2078573

Try adding thunderbolt.host_reset=0 to your kernel command line.

This works for me.
